OAuth Redirect URI for Instagram Basic Display with expo
I am writing a react native app (using expo). The app is supposed to support connecting to Instagram via Instagram Basic Display. After authentication, I want the user to be redirected back to the app. This should ideally work while developing with expo go and later for production builds.
The problem is that the uri that is generated by Linking.createURL(""), exp://10.5...., is not accepted as a valid redirect uri. The error I get is: "Invalid Request: Request parameters are invalid: Invalid redirect_uri".
Linking.createURL() actually expects an argument for deep linking. I do not know an empty string makes sense as I do not yet have a good understanding of how expo handles the redirect.
I tried various arguments for createURL, non of which resulted in a different outcome than the one described above.
